# Add image/badge on Angular 6 Card Botton-Center border

Tags: angular, angular6

I am currently developing a search panel using Angular 6 and i would like to have a 'arrow' image or badge on a card bottom-center border which will be used to toggle show/hide the search panel. The required output is shown below [image: sample image] Can anyone suggest me what can be done to achieve the output.

```
<div *ngIf="isSearchVisible" class="search-panel-lower">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
         <!--Code here-->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to put a button like that there? Or how to show/hide the panel, or how to style the button that way? What have you tried?

Comment: @ChrisW. How to put a button there. I have done the toggle part. Is there any libraries i could use to add a button on the border or should i use CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a button using CSS like this.

```
    <div class="card" style="position:relative;overflow:initial;">
        <div class="card-title">
            title
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
            content
        </div>
        <!-- button code -->
        <div style="position:absolute;text-align:center;width:100%;bottom:-10px;">button icon</div>
    </div>
```